# Using SSL and SslStream for peer to peer authentication?

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, sslstream

I need to provide secure communication between various processes that are using TCP/IP sockets for communication.  I want both authentication and encryption.  Rather than re-invent the wheel I would really like to use SSL and the SslStream class and self-signed certificates.  What I want to do is validate the remote process's certificate against a known copy in my local application.  (There doesn't need to be a certificate authority because I intend for the certificates to be copied around manually).

To do this, I want the application to be able to automatically generate a new certifiate the first time it is run.  In addition to makecert.exe, it looks like [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/dcook/archive/2008/11/25/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c.aspx) shows a way to automatically generate self-signed certificates, so that's a start.

I've looked at the AuthenticateAsServer and AuthenticateAsClient methods of SslStream.  You can provide call-backs for verification, so it looks like it's possible.  But now that I'm into the details of it, I really don't think it's possible to do this.

Am I going in the right direction?  Is there a better alternative?  Has anyone done anything like this before (basically peer-to-peer SSL rather than client-server)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Step 1:** Generating a self-signed certificate:

- I downloaded the [Certificate.cs class](http://blogs.msdn.com/dcook/archive/2008/11/25/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c.aspx) posted by Doug Cook
- I used this code to generate a .pfx certificate file:

  ```
  byte[] c = Certificate.CreateSelfSignCertificatePfx(
          "CN=yourhostname.com", //host name
          DateTime.Parse("2000-01-01"), //not valid before
          DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01"), //not valid after
          "mypassword"); //password to encrypt key file

      using (BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(
          File.Open(@"testcert.pfx", FileMode.Create)))
      {
          binWriter.Write(c);
      }
  ```

**Step 2:** Loading the certificate

```
    X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2(
                            @"testcert.pfx", 
                            "mypassword");
```

**Step 3:** Putting it together

- I based it on [this very simple SslStream example](http://leastprivilege.com/2005/02/28/sslstream-sample/)
- You will get a compile time error about the SslProtocolType enumeration.  Just change that from SslProtocolType.Default to SslProtocols.Default
- There were 3 warnings about deprecated functions. I replaced them all with the suggested replacements.
- I replaced this line in the Server Program.cs file with the line from Step 2:

  X509Certificate cert = getServerCert();
- In the Client Program.cs file, make sure you set serverName = yourhostname.com (and that it matches the name in the certificate)
- In the Client Program.cs, the CertificateValidationCallback function fails because sslPolicyErrors contains a RemoteCertificateChainErrors.  If you dig a little deeper, this is because the issuing authority that signed the certificate is not a trusted root.
- I don`t want to get into having the user import certificates into the root store, etc., so I made a special case for this, and I check that certificate.GetPublicKeyString() is equal to the public key that I have on file for that server.  If it matches, I return True from that function.  That seems to work.

**Step 4:** Client Authentication

Here's how my client authenticates (it's a little different than the server):

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(hostName, port);

SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallback),
    new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(CertificateSelectionCallback));

bool authenticationPassed = true;
try
{
    string serverName = System.Environment.MachineName;

    X509Certificate cert = GetServerCert(SERVER_CERT_FILENAME, SERVER_CERT_PASSWORD);
    X509CertificateCollection certs = new X509CertificateCollection();
    certs.Add(cert);

    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(
        serverName,
        certs,
        SslProtocols.Default,
        false); // check cert revokation
}
catch (AuthenticationException)
{
    authenticationPassed = false;
}
if (authenticationPassed)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The CertificateValidationCallback is the same as in the server case, but note how AuthenticateAsClient takes a collection of certificates, not just one certificate.  So, you have to add a LocalCertificateSelectionCallback, like this (in this case, I only have one client cert so I just return the first one in the collection):

```
static X509Certificate CertificateSelectionCallback(object sender,
    string targetHost,
    X509CertificateCollection localCertificates,
    X509Certificate remoteCertificate,
    string[] acceptableIssuers)
{
    return localCertificates[0];
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because you managed to link to a site that is now gone. **Don’t rely on links to other sites.** Just post the code here next time. :(

Comment: What I don't get...Where do you get the server Certificate from.
X509Certificate cert = GetServerCert(SERVER_CERT_FILENAME, SERVER_CERT_PASSWORD);

Comment: @pimboden - it's from the code linked in step 2 (maybe)

Answer (score 2):

you can look too this example 
Sample Asynchronous SslStream Client/Server Implementation
http://blogs.msdn.com/joncole/archive/2007/06/13/sample-asynchronous-sslstream-client-server-implementation.aspx

if certificate is not produced correctly you can get exception The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.

basic certificate example

makecert -sr LocalMachine -ss My -n CN=Test -sky exchange -sk 123456

or

as external file

makecert -sr LocalMachine -ss My -n CN=Test -sky exchange -sk 123456 c:\Test.cer

Certificate Creation Tool (Makecert.exe)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you're proposing sounds fine to me, except that it sounds like you're looking to wait until the callback is invoked in order to generate the certificate. I don't think that that will fly; AFAIK, you've got to provide a valid certificate when you invoke `AuthenticateAsX`.

However, these classes are overridable; so in theory, you could create a derived class which first checks to see if a certificate needs to be generated, generates it if need be, then invokes the parent `AuthenticateAsX` method.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  When I install the program, the first time it runs it would generate a new certificate.  The server would call AuthenticateAsServer and pass this certificate, the client would call AuthenticateAsClient and pass it's certificate.  But SslStream will probably throw an exception

Comment: What exception would you expect, and why? Self-signed certificates should be acceptable to the SSL stack (try saying that five times fast :-)

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try and post the results.