# How to implement P2P in C#?

Tags: c#, p2p

Recently, I would like to develop a simple chat program using c# and Winform,Main feature is chat and file transfer ,But i can't found example about implement p2p using dotnet,Who can help me?

Comment: Here is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695802/using-ssl-and-sslstream-for-peer-to-peer-authentication) I answered about how to do peer to peer connections over SSL in C#. It might be of some assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

Comment: Incredibly terse, but accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to implement p2p functionality or a specific p2p protocol?

For generic p2p functionality, or any kind of communication functionality, you should probably use WCF.

For specific p2p protocols, like [direct connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_(file_sharing)), [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_(protocol)) and the like you need to decide first which protocol you want to use, and most likely there will be an already existing .Net library for it.

Comment: Thanks!
I don't want to implement a specific p2p protocol,My aim is to make on the Internet between two computers communicate with each other,And that both computers are on different LAN